# Anyway that I can make sure that the matrix I generated meet the criteria both in row and in column in R?

Tags: r

I want to generate a 12*12 matrix with each row and column has exactly 6 odds and 6 evens ranging from 1-12. For each column, there is no duplicate number.

The problem is that I only know how to set number for rows and columns separately. When I make sure that the column is correct, the rows have some problems. Anyway that I can make sure that the criteria for the rows and the columns reach simultaneously?

I'm a completely newbee so forgive me writing such a long code for this simple function :(

Here is the R code that I wrote:

```
set.seed(123)mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 12, ncol = 12)

for (i in 1:12) 
{ 
even_nums <- sample(seq(2, 12, 2), 6) 
odd_nums <- sample(seq(1, 11, 2), 6)
row_nums <- sample(c(even_nums, odd_nums)) 

while (sum(row_nums %% 2 == 0) != 6 | sum(row_nums %% 2 == 1) != 6) { 
even_nums <- sample(seq(2, 12, 2), 6) 
odd_nums <- sample(seq(1, 11, 2), 6) 
row_nums <- sample(c(even_nums, odd_nums)) 
} 
mat[i, ] <- row_nums }

for (j in 1:12) 
{ 
even_nums <- sample(seq(2, 12, 2), 6)
odd_nums <- sample(seq(1, 11, 2), 6)
col_nums <- sample(c(even_nums, odd_nums))
while (any(duplicated(col_nums)) | sum(col_nums %% 2 == 0) != 6 | sum(col_nums %% 2 == 1) != 6) 
{  
even_nums <- sample(seq(2, 12, 2), 6)
odd_nums <- sample(seq(1, 11, 2), 6) 
col_nums <- sample(c(even_nums, odd_nums)) 
} 
mat[, j] <- col_nums

}

mat
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a random n-by-n matrix where each of `1:n` appears exactly once in each column and exactly once in each row:

```
matrix(sequence(rep(n, n), sample(0:(n - 1L)))%%n + 1L, n, n)[sample(n),]
```

However, this is overconstrained, since duplicates are prohibited only within columns. To relax the constraint so that each row need only have 6 evens and 6 odds, shuffle the evens among themselves within each column and do the same for the odds.

Example with `n = 12`:

```
n <- 12L
s0 <- matrix(1:n, 2)
m <- matrix(sequence(rep(n, n), sample(0:(n - 1L)))%%n + 1L, n, n)[sample(n),]
m[] <- replicate(n, c(rbind(sample(s0[1,]), sample(s0[2,]))))[cbind(c(m), c(col(m)))]
m
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#>  [1,]    2    6    9    6    3   11    9   12   12     4     1    11
#>  [2,]   11    1    6    1   12    8    4    3    9     7    10    10
#>  [3,]    8    4    3    4   11    3    1    6    2     2    11     7
#>  [4,]   12    8    1    8    5    9    3   10   10     6     7     9
#>  [5,]   10   10    5    2    1    7    7    4    8     8     5     1
#>  [6,]    7   11   12    7   10   10   12    7    7     9     4     2
#>  [7,]    5    7    2   11    2    6    2    1    3     5     6    12
#>  [8,]    6   12    7   12    7    5   11    2    6    10     9     3
#>  [9,]    4    2   11   10    9    1    5    8    4    12     3     5
#> [10,]    3    9    8    3    4    2   10    9    1    11    12     8
#> [11,]    9    3    4    5    8   12    8    5   11     1     2     6
#> [12,]    1    5   10    9    6    4    6   11    5     3     8     4
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! Your answer is very helpful to me, but somehow I got an error message stating “Error in sequence(rep(n, n), sample(0:(n - 1L))) :  unused argument (sample(0:(n - 1)))“”. I tried to look into why I got this, but I have no clue... Could you let me know how I can fix it? Thank you very much!

Comment: My guess is that either you are running an old version of R or you have a package installed with a `sequence` function that is conflicting with `base::sequence`. What version of R are you running, and what do you get when you enter `?sequence`?

Comment: Yes, i believe it is because i have other packages installed with a sequence function. The problem is well-solved. Thank you so much for your help!